# Regex to check for default value requestPathInvalidCharacters

Tags: .net, regex, asp.net-mvc

I need a regex to validate username using the [RegularExpressionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute.aspx) . It should match username that doesn't contains any of the default value for the [requestPathInvalidCharacters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.requestpathinvalidcharacters.aspx) (<,>,*,%,&,:,\,?).

So it should match

> aafa.
>
> aaf8-a
>
> aafa

It shouldn't match

> `aa<fa`
>
> aaf>a
>
> aaf*a
>
> aafa*
>
> aaf%a
>
> aaf&a
>
> aaf:a
>
> aaf\a
>
> aaf?a

So far I have been tweaking this regex but it still fail in one of those cases...

```
^(?!.*(<|>|\*|%|&|:|\\|\?).*)$
```

> ```
>     [Fact]
>     public void CanValidateAgainstInvalidCharacter()
>     {
>         var result = true;
>         Assert.True(result);
> ```

```
        var listWeDontWant = @"<,>,*,%,&,:,\,?";
        var inner = listWeDontWant.Split(',').Select(x => Regex.Escape(x)).Aggregate((s, s1) => s + "|" + s1);
        //inner = @"\\";
        var pattern = @"^(?!.*(" + inner + ").*)$";

        Debug.WriteLine(pattern);

        //var isMatch = ;

        //Debug.WriteLine(isMatch);
        pattern = @"^[^<>*%&:\\\?]+$";
        Assert.False(Regex.IsMatch("aaf\a", pattern));

      //  Assert.True(Regex.IsMatch("aafa.", pattern));
       // Assert.True(Regex.IsMatch("aaf8-a", pattern));
        //Assert.True(Regex.IsMatch("aafa", pattern));
        //Assert.True(Regex.IsMatch("aafa", pattern));
        //Assert.True(Regex.IsMatch("aa,fa", pattern));
        //Assert.True(Regex.IsMatch("aafa", pattern));

        //Assert.False(Regex.IsMatch("aa<fa", pattern));
        //Assert.False(Regex.IsMatch("aaf>a", pattern));
        //Assert.False(Regex.IsMatch("aaf*a", pattern));
        //Assert.False(Regex.IsMatch("aafa*", pattern));
        //Assert.False(Regex.IsMatch("aaf%a", pattern));
        //Assert.False(Regex.IsMatch("aaf&a", pattern));
        //Assert.False(Regex.IsMatch("aaf:a", pattern));
        //Assert.False(Regex.IsMatch("aaf\a", pattern));
        //Assert.False(Regex.IsMatch("aaf?a", pattern));

    }
```

Comment: Is guessing which one of those cases it fails for part of the game? If not, maybe you could tell us.

Comment: Guessing is not part of the game. However as I tweak the expression it start to fail on one of these test. Let me update my question with a test cases that I have been using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't that just be

```
^[^<>*%&:\\\?]+$
```

or

```
^[^<>*%&:\\\?]*$
```

if empty string is valid

Or with automation if `invalid` contains the RequestPathInvalidCharacters

```
var regex = new Regex(string.Format("^[^{0}]*$",
                                    Regex.Escape(string.Join("",invalid.Split(',')))));
```

Comment: that's what I thought at first too... but this test failed.           
var pattern = @"^[^<>*%&:\\\?]+$";
Assert.False(Regex.IsMatch("aaf\a", pattern));

Comment: @firefly, the string you are parsing in doesn't contain a \ it contains \a which is a special character. Try `Assert.IsFalse(Regex.IsMatch(@"aa\a",pattern))`

Comment: Ah that took care of it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You're expecting `"aaf\a"` to fail the match, but it doesn't since `\a` is an escaped character "a". Thus, the regex matches the string since an escaped "a" is allowed. I suspect you expected it to fail if the string contains a backslash `\`. In that case change your sample string and escape the backslash, or use a verbatim string:

```
Regex.IsMatch("aaf\\a", pattern)  // escaped
Regex.IsMatch(@"aaf\a", pattern)  // verbatim string
```

With that change in place, the `@"^[^<>*%&:\\\?]+$"` pattern will work and your assertion should pass.

As for your negative look-ahead pattern, it's currently accepting more than it should since it's asserting whether a match is possible, but not actually consuming any text, so it yields positive matches when that's not what's intended. To fix this behavior, add something to the pattern to actually match (and consume) the text.

```
// added ".+" before the final "$"
var pattern = @"^(?!.*(" + inner + ").*).+$";
```

Comment: This is the best answer. But since Bob answered before you did (and is also correct although a lot less details) I marked his as the accepted one. 

So it turn out I was writing bad test cases...I had the correct expression all along (before I started tweaking) and turn down the wrong path.

Thanks again for your detail explanation.